# Pass two parameters to ng model - Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm newbie with angular8.
I have the following template:

```
<label class="pr-1 selectLabel" [title]="'alphOrder' | translate">{{'alphOrder' | translate}}</label>
<ng-select class="w-25 p-3" placeholder="Select" [items]="(sortingField | async)?.alphOrder" [clearable]="false" [(ngModel)]="HERE" (change)="sortBy('titles', HERE)" [searchable]="false">
</ng-select>
```

On the first line I passed a key to `[title]` with the `translate` function.
I would like to do the same thing on the second line with `[(ng-model)]`, with the difference of passing **two** parameters.
Then I would like to pass the same parameters to the `sortBy` function. 
In both circumstances the parameters must have the `translate` function.
I would like to understand how to write such a thing, since I never know how to behave with the template syntax...!

Comment: For your model, you need to handle the translation inside your `TypeScript` code.

Comment: It's already done. I just have to figure out how to pass two translatable parameters instead of one...

Comment: You can't, if you are updating the model then what is the need for two parameters?

Comment: If you are setting the same values in both variables you can make them as a single variable. or you can use the `(change)` function to set multiple variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turn the problem around according to your needs.
If you don't have too many elements, you could do something like that in the template (considering that on all the `json` files of the languages ​​you have put all the same keys):

```
<ng-select (change)="sortBy(selection)" [(ngModel)]="selection" class="w-25 p-3" placeholder="Select" [clearable]="false" [searchable]="false">
    <ng-option>{{'author' | translate}}</ng-option>
    <ng-option>{{'title' | translate}}</ng-option>
    <ng-option>{{'date' | translate}}</ng-option>

    <!-- and you can continue to unwind elements if there are not too many ... -->

</ng-select>
```

And that's about the template. 
As for the component `ts` file, you can trigger the selected element like this:

```
export class myComponent {

    public val: string;

    sortBy(val) {
        console.log("Dropdown selection:", val);

        // do whatever you want with the translatable element 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually | translate is a pip.
Your ng model is has a two way binding. So you cant dotwo way binding with a pip.
You have to break it into two parts.

- Model to view binding
- ngModelChange

Here is some example - >
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tn9cbn?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts&view=preview